# inserting custom text to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot graph that I would like to insert custom string below 0 as "Within" and above 0 as "Breached".

I am doing this:

```
ggplot(z, aes(Date, Breach1/60, group=Jobs, label=c("Within SLA", "Breached SLA"))) + 
 geom_line(size=1) + 
 theme_bw() + ylab("Hours") + xlab("Date") + opts(title="Jobs") + 
 geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="red", size=2) + geom_text(hjust=0, vjust=3)
```

This seems to put text all over the place. I like to put one text above the zero and one text below the zero value. Any ideas?

Comment: You should include sample data and include your current graph so that we can recreate your problem and provide a solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are after annotate:

```
ggplot(z, aes(Date, Breach1/60, group=Jobs)) + 
 geom_line(size=1) + 
 theme_bw() + ylab("Hours") + xlab("Date") + opts(title="Jobs") + 
 geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="red", size=2) + 
 annotate("text", label = "Within SLA", x = 1, y = 2) +
 annotate("text", label = "Breached", x = 1, y = -2)
```

Comment: this is fine but when I put the x and y values, my graphs go back in date. How do I put x and y values so that my chart does not change?

Comment: @user1471980 Well since you provided no data I had to guess, just change the x in annotate to whatever you need.

Comment: Is it possible to use annotate when the plot is empty and thus there are no x and y coordinates to define the placement? I would just want a centered text!